# Short Film from the 80's with a character made from sand

Tags: story-identification, short-film

I'm trying to locate a short film from early 1980s. 
The main character (he or she) was made of sand or something to look like this and the whole thing was sand stop-motion.

There were different landscapes and s/he would break up, then s/he would fall through the floor of one land to get to the next one.

Not a very colourful film as I vaguely remember, but I loved this short film as was only about 10 years old at the time.

Comment: https://www.nfb.ca/playlists/stop-motion-animation/viewing/sand_castle/

Comment: Hi. Sorry should of put this in.... It is sand stop-motion.

Comment: Was the film 2D (flat on a plate) or 3D? Was this colourful sand or just plain yellow?

Comment: Not to ask a personal question, but can you not just ask your parents/carers/brothers/sisters, etc who were in the room when you watched it?

Comment: If either of the answers I've provided is correct, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: I believe you are looking for this one: https://youtu.be/hzvqmoPu2H4?feature=shared

Answer (score 1):

After posting my last answer, I found a second match with the same search that might better match, albeit from a later timeframe. *[Quest](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117419/)*, by Thomas Stellmach, was released in 1996 and according to [one review](https://www.imdb.com/review/rw3372677/?ref_=tt_urv) does involve him falling through to other worlds.

> It is claymation with very good stop motion and interesting backgrounds of a character made out of sand leaving his world of sand as he hears the sound of water and falling through various other worlds as he follows the sound of the water dripping down. We enter a world of paper, stone and iron all allowing the animator to work with different themes and texture.
>
> The problem I had that although the animation was very good with some magnificent detail the story left me nonplussed. The character falls through different worlds and each world seems to get more advanced until he falls through the industrial world as he continues his quest. It just all looked like a message of the dangers of industrialisation but maybe I expected something more.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be the 1977 *[Le château de sable](https://letterboxd.com/film/the-sand-castle/)* (*Sand Castle*)?

> o Hoedeman’s Oscar winning animated short is a charming story about creation, diversity and teamwork. A man made of sand creates a bizarre assortment of sand-based characters to help him build a beautiful sand castle they can all call home. The stop-frame animation may appear simplistic but it is not without its charm, particularly in the playful way the odd menagerie of friends are created from their surroundings and the sense of wonder that is conveyed in their creation.

Found with a search for *film "made of sand" stop motion*